# Resending form (F5)

Tags: javascript, php

There is one that sends the POST request to itself. After the script is executed, everything is fine, but when you press F5, the script works again. How to prohibit this? The redirect does not work, for some reason.

```html
<?php
$img = $_FILES['img'];
$headerurl = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=".$id;
if(isset($_POST)) { 
    if($img['name'] != '') {
        $filename = $img['tmp_name'];
        $client_id = "123456789";
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        $pvars = array('image' => base64_encode($data));
        $timeout = 30;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $pms = json_decode($out, true);
        $url = $pms['data']['link'];
        $creator = $_SESSION['login'];
        if($url != ""){
            mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO gallery (steamid, url, creator) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$url."', '".$creator."')") or die(mysqli_error($link));
            //header('Location: ' . $headerurl); //not work
            //header('Location: https://google.com'); //not work
        } else {
            echo "<h4>Error: </h4>";
            echo $pms['data']['error'];  
        } 
    }
}
?>  

<form action="<?php echo $headerurl; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </label>
    <input name="img" type="file" alt="Add Photos" id="file-upload" onchange="this.form.submit()">
</form>
```

Comment: I would be interested to know where you get `$id` from in the second line of code, this line `$headerurl = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=".$id;`

Comment: the full code of the page does not fit here. I think this is not so important, but if so it is necessary: `if (isset($_GET['id'])) { ... $id  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['id']); ... }`

Comment: The problem is different, the code works.

Comment: "The redirect does not work" - what does that mean? Why is that not working?

Comment: @Nico Haase, after POST, it remains on the same page.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this? What does `$url` contain - does it even contain anything such that the redirect is called?

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect the page after post processing is completed

```
<?php
...
if(isset($_POST)) { 
    ....
    header('Location: '.$newURL);
}
?>
```

Comment: -_-. I tried it. Redirection does not work. Remains on the same page and resending the form is triggered after pressing F5.

Comment: Something should be suppressed on the screen while being directed by header.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a right way. But put `header("location: yourlocation/");` to redirect

Comment: -_-. I tried it. Redirection does not work. Remains on the same page and resending the form is triggered after pressing F5.

Comment: And what does the wrong way mean? Why do you think so?

Comment: Use tokens. Verify token before execute the function. Do not allow duplicate tokens

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20756214)

Comment: Yeah @JessedeBruijne I just said that to prevent duplicate action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code bro...

```
<?php
$img = $_FILES['img'];
$headerurl = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=".$id;
if(isset($_POST)){ 
    if($img['name'] != '') {
        $filename = $img['tmp_name'];
        $client_id = "123456789";
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        $pvars = array('image' => base64_encode($data));
        $timeout = 30;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $pms = json_decode($out, true);
        $url = $pms['data']['link'];
        $creator = $_SESSION['login'];
        if($url != ""){
           $result =  mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO gallery (steamid, url, creator) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$url."', '".$creator."')");

            if($result){

                header("location: google.com");

            }else{

                echo "<h4>Error: </h4>";

            }

        } else {
            echo "<h4>Error: </h4>";
            echo $pms['data']['error'];  
        } 
    }
}
?> 

<form action="<?php echo $headerurl; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </label>
    <input name="img" type="file" alt="Add Photos" id="file-upload" onchange="this.form.submit()">
</form>
```